# Remove attribute of HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove the attribute of the first HTML `<div>` tag? So, this:

```
<div style="display: none; ">aaa</div>
```

becomes

```
<div>aaa</div>
```

from the following:

```
<div style="display: none; ">aaa</div>
<a href="#" style="display: none; ">(bbb)</a>
<span style="display: none; ">ccc</span>​
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remvove it from literally the first element use [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$(":first").removeAttr("style");
```

or in this case [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) will show the element by removing the `display` property:

```
$(":first").show();
```

---

Though you probably want to narrow it down to inside something else, for example:

```
$("#container :first").removeAttr("style");
```

If you want to show the first hidden one, use [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) as your selector:

```
$(":hidden:first").show();
```

Comment: Your first example `$(":first")` doesn't limit itself to the content of the `body` tag, which I assume is the intention. http://jsfiddle.net/jqB2b/ Using `$('body :first')` works. http://jsfiddle.net/jqB2b/1/

Comment: Nick - OK, fair enough. :o) But still worth noting since the first part doesn't do what I assume the OP wanted given the markup in the question.

Answer (score 37):

Or pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('id?').removeAttribute('attribute?')
```

Comment: jQuery does not always work when jscript is being used at the same time. I get $ undefined errors. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact jQuery has something for this purpose: http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method like this:

```
$('div[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Since you have not specified any id or class for the div, the above code finds a div having inline style in it and then it removes that style from it.

If you know there is some parent element of the div with an id, you can use this code instead:

```
$('#parent_id div[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

Where `parent_id` is supposed to be the id of parent element containing the div under question.

Comment: It will remove the style from all divs, while the OP ask specifically for the first one ..

Comment: @Gaby: I have also pointed out if there is parent element. For the first div `:first` filter selector will be needed as already  pointed out :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: I meant in *your* answer, sorry should have clarified that :)

Answer (score 0):

You say "remove the attribute" — do you mean to remove **all** attributes? Or remove the `style` attribute specifically?

Let's start with the latter:

```
$('div').removeAttr('style');
```

The `removeAttr` function simply removes the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy in jQuery just use

```
$("div:first").removeAttr("style");
```

in javascript

use var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

divs[0].removeAttribute("style");