# Remove rel attribute from a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove attribute of html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909555/remove-attribute-of-html-tag)

I have some jQuery in my code that adds a rel attribute to all a tags in my code.  I don't want to remove the code that adds these rel attributes but instead wanted to remove these rel attributes using JavaScript/jQuery.  I am able to do reset the rel attributes to empty string thus:

```
var $this = $(this);
var $items = $this.find('a');
$items.attr('rel', '');
```

Instead though, what I'd like to do is remove the rel tag altogether.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Correct the code that creates the attributes, don't paper over the faults. Though [`removeattr()`](http://API.jquery.com/removeattr/) is what you think you need.

Comment: `rel` is not a tag btw. It's an attribute.

Comment: @David the reason for papering over the cracks as it were is because the code I'm using is a third party library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `removeAttr()` http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

```
$items.removeAttr('rel');
```