# remove action attribute of form

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the action attribute action of a form on page load?

My form is

```
<form action="process" class="TTWForm ui-sortable-disabled" method="post"
      novalidate="">


           <div id="field2-container" class="field f_100 ui-resizable-disabled ui-state-disabled">
                <label for="field2">
                     Comments
                </label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="field2" id="field2" required="required"></textarea>
           </div>


           <div id="field3-container" class="field f_100 radio-group required ui-resizable-disabled ui-state-disabled">

                <label for="field3-1">
                     Work
                </label>


                <div class="option clearfix">
                     <input name="field3" id="field3-1" value="Needs Revisions" type="radio">
                     <span class="option-title">
                          Needs Revisions
                     </span>
                </div>


                <div class="option clearfix">

                     <input name="field3" id="field3-2" value="Fine" type="radio">
                     <span class="option-title">
                          Fine
                     </span>
                </div>


                <div class="option clearfix">
                     <input name="field3" id="field3-3" value="Unstable" type="radio">
                     <span class="option-title">
                          Unstable
                     </span>

                </div>
           </div>


           <div id="form-submit" class="field f_100 clearfix submit">
                <input value="Submit" type="submit">
           </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove attribute of html tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909555/remove-attribute-of-html-tag) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: The first google result for "jquery remove attribute" goes to the documenation of `.removeAttr()`.

Comment: if you want to remove it as the page loads, why not leave it away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('form.TTWForm.ui-sortable-disabled').attr('action', '');
});
```

Or:

```
$(function(){
    $('form.TTWForm.ui-sortable-disabled').removeAttr('action');
});
```

If you want to change it's value to `foo`:

```
$(function(){
    $('form.TTWForm.ui-sortable-disabled').attr('action', 'foo');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the form and then use jQuery's [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method to remove the attribute.

Something like this:

```
// Wait for the document to be ready
$(function(){
   // Remove the attribute from the form
   $("form.TTWForm.ui-sortable-disabled").removeAttr("action");
});
```