# How can I strip HTML tags that have attribute(s) from string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have a question and answer website like SO. Also I have a textarea and a preview under it *(exactly the same as SO)*. I use a markdown library to converts some symbols to HTML tags. For example that JS library replaces `**` with `<b>`. Ok all fine.

Now I need to escape HTML tags that have attribute. I can do that by PHP like [this](https://3v4l.org/DA1bJ):

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <p>These line shall stay</p>
    <p class="myclass">Remove this one</p>
    <p>But keep this</p>
    <div style="color: red">and this</div>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$lines_to_be_removed = $xpath->query("//*[count(@*)>0]");

foreach ($lines_to_be_removed as $line) {
    $line->parentNode->removeChild($line);
}

// just to check
echo $dom->saveHtml($dom->documentElement);
?>
```

I'm not sure code above is the best, but as you see *(in the fiddle I've linked)* it works as expected. I mean it removes nodes that are at least one attribute. Now I need to do that by JS *(or jQuery)* *(I need this for that textarea preview simulator)*. Anyway how can I do that? Do I need regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove attribute of HTML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909555/remove-attribute-of-html-tag)

Comment: @Sherif No no .. this isn't duplicate. I don't want to remove attribute part of the tag. I need to remove the tag completely *(the node)* if it has at least one attribute.

Comment: No, [regex is not the tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Parse it as a document and remove those nodes. Exactly how will depend on your input and environment.

Comment: My mistake. I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.myTextArea *').each(function(){
    if (this.attributes.length)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b1bejxxr/)

It's not the most efficient, but if it's just a textarea preview it should be fine. I'd recommend running it as little as possible though. As far as I know there is no selector (jQuery or otherwise) that would otherwise do this...so you have to make the JS do the work.

---

Edit based on comment:

To not remove the element, just the surrounding tag, do something like this:

```
$('.myTextArea *').each(function(){
    if (this.attributes.length)
        this.outerHTML = this.textContent;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kmoovv9t/)

Comment: Great, upvote. thank you .. just your approach removes a node completely. Actually I'm trying to keep the content node but drop the `<tag attribute` container that surround it.

Comment: I mimicked the PHP demo...is that not what you want? ...so leave the text and just lose the surrounding tag?

Comment: Yes exactly .. I want to just lose the surrounding tag and leae the text

Comment: Well and well done :-) thank you again .. just one thing, there is some [useless spaces surround the text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O37b0.png), can't I remove them?

Comment: @MartinAJ - that's probably actually just the space that was previously around the element (the tabs/spaces from its indentation, the newline after it, etc). To be honest it would be better to wrap the text in a new span rather than just remove the containing tag, such as `this.outerHTML = '<span>'+this.textContent+'</span>';`

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript `element.attributes` property returns a live `NamedNodeMap` of a tags attributes and their values.  For example...

**HTML**

```
<div class=".cls" id="id" title="divtitle">
    <!-- content ... -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var div = document.getElementById('id');
var attr = div.attributes;

console.log(attr);
/* => 
NamedNodeMap [class="cls", id="id", title="divtitle"]
*/
```

This can be used to filter selected items - something like this for your example...

```
/* return an array from querySelectorAll */
var paras = Array.prototype.slice.call(
       document.querySelectorAll('div p')
);

/* loop through paras */
paras.forEach(function(p) {
    /* 'p' = each element in 'paras' */

    /* get attributes of 'p' */
    var attr = p.attributes;

    /* only check elements with attributes */
    if (attr.length != 0) {

        /* loop through attributes */
        Object.keys(attr).forEach(function(a) {
            /* apply conditional */
            if (attr[a].name === 'class' && attr[a].value === 'myclass' ||
                attr[a].name === 'style' && attr[a].value === 'color: red;') {

                /* remove element ('p') */
                p.parentElement.removeChild(p);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Because a `NamedNodeMap` is a type of Object I used `Object.keys(obj)` to return an array of keys, and then looped over them to determine the attribute's `.name` and `.value` properties.

**EDIT: In light of comment above**

If you just want to remove the attributes then you can drop the condition above, like so...

```
paras.forEach(function(p) {
    var attr = p.attributes;
    if (attr.length != 0) {
        Object.keys(attr).forEach(function(a) {
            p.removeAttribute(a);
        });
    }
});
```

See:

- [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)
- [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)
- [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Element.removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)