# jquery delete style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove style attribute from my HTML elements but only from one div, not full html code. For example:

```
<div class="row" style="width: 100px"></div>
<div class="container"><p style="font-size: 12px"></p> </div>
```

I want only delete 'style' from all elements in div with class 'container'.

Comment: How do you want to do that? Please, rerwrite the question

Comment: It would make more sense to just remove the `style` attribute directly from your HTML. Although note that you shouldn't really be using them at all in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove attribute of HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909555/remove-attribute-of-html-tag)

Comment: You should chose palash solution as answer, he was first after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) & [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) like:

```
$('div.container').children().removeAttr('style');
```

DEMO:

```js
$('div.container')
  .children()   // Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements
  .removeAttr('style'); // Remove style attribute from each element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="width: 100px"></div>
<div class="container">
  <p style="font-size: 12px">Test 1</p>
  <p style="color: green; font-size: 12px">Test 2</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container2">
  <p style="font-size: 12px">Test 1</p>
  <p style="color: green; font-size: 12px">Test 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove the style attribute from the children in `div.container`.

Comment: Minor point: you could use `$(".container [style]")` as a selector instead of using `.children()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan which would satisfy what OP asked for - "all elements in div with class 'container'"

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.container*').attr('style','');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(".container").removeAttr("style")
```