# How to delete data-toggle attribute from div - wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, attributes

[I want to delete this data-toggle attribute from wordpress, but i don't know how.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRko.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove attribute of HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909555/remove-attribute-of-html-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `removeAttribute()` method of `HTMLElement`.

First, you need to select the element. There are several ways, I prefer to use `querySelector()`.
The query selects a `a` element with the class `cart-contents` and the attribute `data-toggle`.

Then, simply call the `removeAttribute` method.

###### Full Code

```js
const $toRemoveAttrElem = window.document.querySelector("a.cart-contents[data-toggle]");
$toRemoveAttrElem.removeAttribute("data-toggle");
```